Cucumber json file generates false positive results for failed scripts when running tests in parallel TestCafe
I have set up Testcafe to test in parallel by setting the concurrency value to 3, meaning that 3 browser instances will be active simultaneously on which different tests will be running. That is all good and working as expected.
https://i.sstatic.net/516WnvqH.png
The problem is once the execution finishes, a cucumber JSON report is generated for the scripts that have finished running containing details like passed/failed, etc...
Here, the JSON file that is generated, notes that all scripts are passed, but there are failed scripts as it can bee seen from the TestCafe report file.
This is the command I am using to run the scripts:
"test:ui": "gherkin-testcafe chrome features/step-definitions/ui/**/*.js features/component/ui/*.feature -w 3 --reporter cucumber-json,html:reports/testcafe-report.html,custom --hostname localhost --skip-js-errors --tags @test -s path=reports/screenshots,takeOnFails=true ;",
(https://i.sstatic.net/6EIXeVBM.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/rUvTLoDk.png)
Does anyone know what might be the issue here?
